# Can boost interval_set or interval_map create clusters with cluster membership counts?

Tags: c++, boost-icl

For example if I have 5 input intervals

```
[0,2]
[1,3]
[2,4]
[5,7]
[6,8]
```

the result should indicate two clusters. Cluster 1

```
[0,4] with a count of 3
[5,8] with a count of 2
```

But I've found that boost::icl::interval map doesn't aggregate clusters, but splits on boundaries.

For example the following test case does not give me the result I hoped for

```
using namespace boost::icl;
interval_map<double,int> map;

map += std::make_pair(interval<double>::right_open(1.0,2.0), 1);
map += std::make_pair(interval<double>::right_open(2.1,3.0), 1);
map += std::make_pair(interval<double>::right_open(2.9,4.0), 1);

std::cerr << map.iterative_size() << std::endl;


EXPECT_EQ(1, map.find(1.5)->second); // passes
EXPECT_EQ(2, map.find(1.0)->second); // passes 
EXPECT_EQ(2, map.find(3.1)->second); // fails
```

and I understand why as this is by design. However is there a different formulation or library I can use to achieve what I require?

I guess what I'd be looking for is a count of the number of merges that occur with boost::icl::interval_set. When a new interval is added to the container it either inserts a new unique interval or merges with a previous interval. However I don't think the number of times the merge occurs is preserved.